# slot filling triggers different intent in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have two intents pizzaSelected and burgerSelected in both intents I am asking for required parameters

I have below entities

```
@pizza [pepperoni, farmhouse, country special, cheese]
@pizzaSize [small, medium, large]
@burger [veg, beef, ham]
@burgerToppings [onion, tomato, lettuce, pepper]
```

expected conversation

```
user: order 2 burgers
bot: which burger?
user: cheese
bot: sorry but we have veg, beef and ham burgers. please select one from this.
user: veg
bot: toppings?
user: tomato and lettuce
bot: you order for 2 veg burgers with tomato and lettuce toppings is placed.
```

actual conversation

```
user: order 2 burgers
bot: which burger?
user: cheese
bot: what size of pizza you want
```

as in actual conv when user says cheese which belongs to @pizza entity then it triggers the pizzaSelected intent instead of re-prompting the user for entering correct value.

Is there a way to handle this.

Comment: Is this a different Intent, or filling a different slot? It would help if you updated your question to include screen shots of the Intents in question, not just the Entities you're using to populate it.

Comment: It is filling a slot of another intent (pizzaSelected)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, could you add screenshots of your intent setup, training phrases and parameters that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using custom fulfilment based logic for slot filing then your burger_type entity (or whichever name you might have used for entity) must have cheese as a valid value.

I would recommend to go to entities and check the values of entity which you are using to store type of burger. Even if you have only the correct values there try reordering them and then save. This will force the bot to retrain as this is a machine learning model sometimes it might get optimized for the wrong output, if that is the case for you then try retraining it.

Comment: hey yatharth thanks for answering but my question is that how can I stop triggering (intent1) while filling slot value for (intent2)

In my case I am asking user for burger type he want, but user says something else suppose he says margarita (which is a pizza type) so I am expecting my bot to reprompt user for correct burger value but instead my bot triggers the pizzaIntent and fills the pizzaType slot.

Comment: That should not happen ideally if you are using the inbuilt slot filing mechanism, but still if it is happening then I would suggest to check the input context for pizza intent. If you have a context active during the slot filing of Burger intent that is an input context for pizza intent then it might confuse dialogflow because dialogflow relies on context heavily for intent matching and even during slot filing it sets some cotexts implicitly to keep track of which slot it is filing. Make sure these contexts are not conflicting with each other.